# Raspberry Pi Bluetooth File Server

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, cloud

I have a samba server running on my home network, and would like to make one that is more portable.  Given that I would be moving between networks, I was wondering if a similar protocol existed that could be implemented through bluetooth rather than wifi.

I appreciate any advice!